# Get information from button on hover instead of on click

Tags: php

I have several groups being displayed as buttons with their value being the group name, example:

- GROUP 1
- GROUP 2
- GROUP 3

At this moment I can click on one of the groups and detect which groups was clicked on using this setup:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql)or die(mysqli_error());
        echo '<input type="hidden" id="clicked-button">';

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
          echo ' <input type="submit" id="submitfakta" name="submitted-btn" value="'.$row['groupName'].'"><div id="faktaboks">
          <p> '.$row['groupName'].' </p>
```

I then use a simple if statement like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submitted-btn'])) {
    $cata = $_POST['submitted-btn']; }
```

I now have the group name in a variable and are using this variable for my sql query to display the correct information for the selected/clicked group.

I want the same result as now but instead of clicking on the button, I would like to just hover on it.

Is there a way you can detect (get the value in a variable to use for the query) which button you are hovering on?

Comment: using PHP or Javascript ?

Comment: PHP is serverside, so no.

Comment: Is there a way you can detect which button you are hovering on?
Is this question ?

Comment: @Googlian yes, meaning how I can get the information in a variable, so that I can use that variable for a correct query to display the information that belongs the button the user is hovering on.

Comment: can't you use onHover in jQuery ?

Comment: You want to submit your form on hover? This is possibe, but you will have to use javascript for this.

Comment: You may want to have a look at ajax, if you plan to use a php-script to fetch some info you need to display on the current site without leaving it.

Comment: Try AJAX to achieve this

Comment: Okay, thank you all. I'll look into AJAX now. Never worked with it before, but I'll be back to update with an answer when I figure it out with AJAX.